# Организация структуры БД. Значения за каждый час - в одном столбце? Или в отдельной таблице?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть лог-файлы, каждый из которых соответствует определённой дате. И каждый содержит несколько тысяч строк. В файлах есть сообщения, у каждого сообщения есть время отправки.
Мне нужно посчитать количество сообщений за сутки и за каждый час.
Если сообщения за сутки - всё просто.
Пришёл к выводу, что нужна таблица со столбцами "Дата" и "Количество сообщений". Одно число соответствует каждой дате.

А сообщения за каждый час? Это получается, число сообщений принадлежит конкретному часу, но час еще принадлежит конкретной дате.
Т. е. каждой дате соответствует набор данных вида (слева час, справа кол-во сообщений):
1 - 234
2 - 125
3 - 137
4 - 563
...

Я сначала думал сделать таблицу с 24 столбцами (по количеству часов), т. к. не нашёл другого решения. Но мне сказали, что это хреновое решение, а как правильно сделать - не объяснили толком. Лишь что в таблице с датами должен быть еще столбец "Час".
Но как в нём организовать данные? Если разделить числа за каждый час символом и разделять при выводе на массив чисел, то это выглядит не слишком экономно.

И правильный ли это совет - с одним столбцом для часа? Идея с 24 столбцами мне и самому не очень нравится.

Comment: "за сутки все просто" - а что мешает сделать аналогичным образом и за часы? Т.е. вместо даты будете писать `2016-03-19 13:00:00` - будет вам за час, а надо за сутки - подсчитали за сутки

Comment: Ни в коем случае не храните числа, разделенные каким-то разделителем - СУБД не приспособлена для работы с таким форматом данных и очень не эффективна на таком наборе. Постарайтесь разместить каждое значение в новой записи - в этом случае вы сможете воспользоваться всей мощью SQL, как в плане поиска, агрегации, индексации.

Comment: @BOPOH, да, что-то я тупанул не слабо. Спасибо за предложение.

Comment: @cheops, ага, я что-то медленно соображаю сегодня. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом. Заведите таблицу с тремя полями

- period_id - тип интервала, 1 - час, (при необходимости 2 - сутки, 3 - неделя, 4 - месяц, 5 - квартал,  6 - год)
- started_at - время начала интервала
- total - количество за период

Тогда вы в таблице можете хранить агрегированную информацию по любым интервалам, started_at - задает начало интервала, а period_id позволяет высчитать его длительность, а значит и время окончания. При желании, можно расшифровать поля period_id в дополнительной таблице. Чтобы исключить случайные дубли, можно добавить уникальный индекс на поля period_id, started_at.

С сырыми, не агрегированными данными такую агрегированную статистику лучше не хранить, однако, для всех интервалов вполне подойдет одна таблица с одним столбцом под значение (total).

Comment: А как вы предполагаете обновлять такую таблицу, так, что бы гарантированно не возникло несогласованности данных ?

Comment: Сам я прибегаю к такой схеме только на добавление - постфактум. Если временной интервал уже завершился, добавляем, интервал еще не завершился - не добавляем его в агрегационную таблицу, а берем информацию из сырых данных.

Comment: Отменное предложение, спасибо.